# Is there a way to "shrink to fit" while using PhantomJS?

Tags: printing, pdf-generation, phantomjs

I've taken a look at this: [Cropping PhantomJS screen capture sized to content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14639960/cropping-phantomjs-screen-capture-sized-to-content) but it's not exactly what I want.

I have a 600x348 pixels element on the screen and would like to capture it on a 5cmx9cm PDF, but it seems that I need to do some zooming to get what I want. Even then it's not really accurate. Is there anyway to get the shrink-to-fit effect on printers?